# access model data in custom validation rule

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have custom validation rule:

```
public function customRule($check)
{


}
```

Inside this rule I would like to access some model data (in database). Of course I can do it like this:

```
$this->id = 23; 
$this->read();
```

But then all the data in current model will be overidden by `read` function (I mean `$this->data[$this->alias][...]` is overridden.

How I can get this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular

```
$result = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array($this->alias . '.' . $this->primaryKey => $id));
```

with the id in the find conditions. And work with the result, it is not overriding the data property.

Comment: Assuming the primary key's name is `id`, the shortcut `$this->findById($id)` would also work and require less to type ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just to note that if you want to get **the full record of the data that is currently being validated** it is always accessible in `$this->data` inside the validation rule as opposed to $check which contains only the data in the **currently validated field**.

If you need to validate based on something that is stored in the DB, you can use `$this->find()` or any of the Model's functions as you are in the Model.

I support @burzum 's answer +1.